# Regex, проверить, содержит ли input строка только числа?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input

```
<?php

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
$tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
$error = '';

if(!$name)
{
$error .= 'Пожалуйста введите ваше имя.<br />';
}

// Проверка телефона
function ValidateTel($valueTel)
{
$regexTel = "/^[0-9]{7,12}$/";
if($valueTel == "") {
return false;
} else {
$string = preg_replace($regexTel, "", $valueTel);
}
return empty($string) ? true : false;
}
if(!$tel)
{
$error .= "Пожалуйста введите телефон.<br />";
}
if($tel && !ValidateTel($tel))
{
$error .= "Введите корректный телефон.<br />";
}


if(!$error)

if(!$valueTel || strlen($valueTel) < 10)
{
$error .= "Пожалуйста введите телефон.<br />";// В этой строчке ставиться минимальное ограничение на написание букв.
}
if(!$error)
{


// Проверка сообщения (length)
if(!$message || strlen($message) < 1)
{
$error .= "Введите ваше сообщение.<br />";// В этой строчке ставиться минимальное ограничение на написание букв.
}
if(!$error)
{


$subject ="Заявка с сайта vpluce.ru";
$name_tema = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($name) ."?=";
$message ="\n\nИмя: ".$name."\n\nНомер телефона: " .$tel."\n\nСообщение: ".$message."\n\n";
$mail = mail("mail@gmail.com", $subject, $message,

"From: ".$name_tema." <".$tel."> "."Reply-To: ".$email." "." X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());


if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}
else
{
echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
}

}
?>
```

не могу добавить в $regexTel = **"/^[0-9]{7,12}$/";**

Что бы проходило в такой вариации
Примеры:
+380501234567 - true

+38(050)1234567 - true

+38050123-45-67 - true

050123-4567 - true

Comment: Следует переформулировать вопрос и назвать его "Валидация номера телефона"

Answer (score 0):

Советую вам поработать над форматированием а то сильно понять где закрылась скобка метода тяжело.

Что касаемо функции можно просто преобразовать строку, удалив разрешенные символы а после привести к `int` и сравнить, если она не изменилась значит всё ок, если изменилась не ок.

```
// удалим разрешенные символы из строки
$phoneCheck = str_replace(['+', ' ', ')', '(', '-'], '', $phone);
// далее приводим к integer
$phoneCheckSumm = (int) $phoneCheck;
// сравниваем две переменные 
if($phoneCheck == $phoneCheckSumm && $phoneCheck >= 7 && $phoneCheck <= 15) {
   echo 'все верно';
} else {
   echo 'что то не так';
}
```

Comment: не я писал, слизал с сети.

Comment: если не трудно, поскажите как связать с моим кодом, а то ну я мягко сказать не шарю.